# Can't fetch contents of IFrame

Tags: php, python, html, iframe

I'm dealing with a page which has one `iframe` header that is used to control pages above it, like "page skip" and "jump to" controls. What I need is just to fetch some information that is located inside this frame. Using a browser its ok. Select with cursor, copy.. its done.

The problem is that I have to get the page contents programmatically with PHP or Python.

So if I try to `urlopen` the main page all I get is HTML contents like

```
<frameset rows="140,*" framespacing="0" frameborder="no" border="0">

    <frame src="/header.do?page=1" name="mainFrame" scrolling="no" noresize="noresize" id="mainFrame" title="mainFrame" marginwidth="0" />

    <frame name="bottomFrame" scrolling="no" noresize="noresize" marginwidth="0" id="bottomFrame" title="bottomFrame" />

</frameset>
```

But when I `urlopen` the `header.do?page=1` file directly it won't load proper information I need. Its like `header.do` only works when iframe embedded, or like if it needs more arguments besides `page=1` that main page is passing to it somehow (I didn't find anything)

Short-case: All I need is just to programmatically fetch some information that is inside an iframe. But this info only loads when file is embedded.
How to deal with it?

Comment: Whatever is inside the IFrame is the result of the URL given in the `src` attribute. Retrieving the information should be as simple as sending a GET to that URL.

Could you post the code that you tried to GET the "/header.do?page=1" URL and what it returned?

Comment: Did some digging and found that indeed the file checks via js/jquery if its loaded via frame or direclty.